# Is there a straight forward way of converting data stored in HDFS to JSON?

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, avro

I have a "|" delimited data file which I need to convert to JSON for further processing.

Sample Data looks like below, first row are the fields

```
A | B | C | D | E
001 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5
002 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5
003 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah that was so easy. Just found it. I'm showing an example with two fields only.

```
A = FOREACH 'ALIAS NAME' GENERATE $0 as id, $1 as salary;
STORE A INTO '/your prefered hdfs location' using JsonStorage();
```

and see the power!!!

Comment: I wouldn't put spaces in "your preffered hdfs location". Glad you figured it out though.